# Hadoop Hive query select and group by from separate tables

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop, hive

Below are the avg_mileage table and the trucks table.

What I'm trying to do is to compile an query which allows me to select or create a table with avg_mileage.avgmpg and group by the trucks.model in order from highest to lowest of avg_mileage.avg_mpg.

Something like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this a simple join rather than a group by? (sorry can't "comment" because I don't have enough rep yet.)

OK, I think I get your question. You've already done.

```
SELECT truckid, avg(mpg) avgmpg FROM truck_mileage GROUP BY truckid;
```

Now you want truck.model rather than truckid, AND you want it sorted?

```
SELECT model, avgmpg FROM avg_mileage JOIN trucks ON (avg_mileage.truckid = trucks.truckid) ORDER BY avgmpg DESC;
```

Try something like that.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working.  Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 6:12 missing EOF at '(' near 'trucks' [ERROR_STATUS]

Comment: Try it again. I forgot a "ON" between trucks and the condition to join on.